why ServerWebExchange-bodyToMono can not be subscribed
    @RequestMapping("/helloworld1234")
    public Mono<String> helloWord122(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        ServerRequest serverRequest = ServerRequest.create(exchange, HandlerStrategies.withDefaults().messageReaders());
        // 1
        serverRequest.bodyToMono(String.class).subscribe(body -> {
            log.info("---" + body);
        });
        // 2
        Mono.just("aaaa").subscribe(aaa -> {
            log.info("---" + aaa);
        });
        return Mono.just("newBody");
    }

why does the
log.info("---" + body);

not print?
i dont know why was that, its so complicated.
